# PHP - dealing with HTML entities that are missing semicolon

Tags: php, regex, html-entities

I'm trying to write a script to parse a remote RSS feed, and output the result in JSON format.

The raw RSS feed contains HTML entities like `&#8211;`, `&#8230;`,etc.

I use `html_entity_decode` on the raw content first, so that `json_encode` will generate correct output:

```
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load('https://www.example.com/feed');
$feed = array();
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    $item = array ( 
        'title' => html_entity_decode($node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8'),
        'desc' => html_entity_decode($node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8'),
        'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
    );
    $feed[] = $item;
}
$data = array();
foreach($feed as $item){
    $data[] = array('url'=>$item['link'],'date'=>date('l, F d, Y g:i A',strtotime($item['date'])),'title'=>$item['title'],'desc'=>$item['desc']);
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

It works well except for **some** HTML entites that are missing semicolons. `html_entity_decode` won't recognize them.

I'm thinking maybe I can use regex to find and fix those entities without semicolons. But I don't know how to write such code. Any idea?

Or is there any other way to deal with this?

Comment: Few sample would help !

Comment: So far I see `&#8211;` and `&#8230;`. Sometimes they have semicolons. Sometimes not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you just want to match `&#` followed with 4 digits that are not followed with `;`. Use

```
'~&#\d{4}(?!;)~'
```

and relace with `$0;`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HsKev1/1).

*Details*:

- `&#` - literal sequence `&#`
- `\d{4}` - 4 digits
- `(?!;)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a `;` right after the 4 digits.

The `$0` in the replacement pattern is the backreference to the whole match value.

PHP snippet:

```
$re = '~&#\d{4}(?!;)~';
$str = '&#8211&#8210&#8211;&#8211;';
$subst = '$0;';
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace("/&#(\d{4})(?!;)/i", "&#$1;", $item['desc']);
```

Comment: Please add some text or explanations to your answer to make it more understandable.